# It's correct to Say: "It was Tough to me?"

Tags: grammar, past-tense

It's correct to say: "It was Tough to me accept the loss of my HD"? (To clarify, i want to talk about the Data loss, not the object itself)

I'm Brazilian, so this structure in Portuguese makes sense, But i'm not sure if 'tough' in this sentence can be used to talk about a difficult time in past. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It was tough for me" would be more correct.

There is a situation where "to" would make sense - if someone else is saying something (like a test question, for example) wasn't tough, you *could* say "it was tough to me", as in "to me" (from my perspective) "it was tough".

In general, "It was tough for me to accept ___" sounds more natural.